# Не меняется цвет текста в строке DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

Пытаюсь поменять цвет текст в строке, но при загрузке формы строка моргнет нужным цветом и опять станет цвет по умолчанию.

```
private void bid_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        for (int i = 0; i < dg_bid.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
              string statusID = dg_bid.Rows[i].Cells["status"].Value.ToString();
              dg_bid.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = core.setColor(statusID);            
        }
        dg_bid.Refresh();
}
```

Если убрать обновление таблицы то вообще не чего не произойдет. Как это можно исправить?

```
public Color setColor(string status)
{
    string type = status;
    Color col;
    col = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64);
    switch (type)
    {
        case "0":
            col = Color.FromArgb(127, 140, 141);
            break;
        case "1":
            col = Color.FromArgb(39, 174, 96);
            break;
        case "2":
            col = Color.FromArgb(142, 68, 173);
            break;
        case "3":
            col = Color.FromArgb(52, 152, 219);
            break;
    }

    return col;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не вникая в детали Вашей задачи, ИМХО в Вашем случае проще всего повесить изменение цвета в желаемой строке DataGrid на его событие RowPrePaint. Вот стартовая точка для Вас:

```
   private void dg_bid_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
   {
       // i - Ваша строка в которой Вы желаете изменить цвет. Как она формируется Вы не рассказали
       if( i < dg_bid.Rows.Count )
          dg_bid.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = core.setColor(statusID);
   }
```

Так все работает

В дополнение к правкам, которые Вы внесли в свой вопрос - такой код у меня отработал без проблем:

```
   public Color setColor(string status)
   {
       string type = status;
       Color col;
       col = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64);
       switch (type)
       {
           case "0":
               col = Color.FromArgb(127, 140, 141);
               break;
           case "1":
               col = Color.FromArgb(39, 174, 96);
               break;
           case "2":
               col = Color.FromArgb(142, 68, 173);
               break;
           case "3":
               col = Color.FromArgb(52, 152, 219);
               break;
       }

       return col;
   }

   private void dtGridView_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
   {
       dtGridView.Rows[1].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = setColor("0");
       dtGridView.Rows[2].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = setColor("1");
       dtGridView.Rows[3].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = setColor("2");
       dtGridView.Rows[4].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = setColor("3");
   }
```

Я использовал без изменений Вашу функцию `Color setColor(string status)`.

Значит Ваши проблемы в другом.

Comment: Прошу прощения забыл указать откуда берется переменная i. Пытался сделать так как вы написали, не получается. Как будто где-то стоит дефолнтый цвет который перекрывает изменения.

Comment: Прежде, чем отправлять решение на форум, я естественно его проверил - у меня работает :). Значит, Вам нужно разбираться, где еще Вы манипулируете с цветом строки. Поэкспериментируйте с тестовой формой с DataGridView, где нет ничего лишнего.

Comment: вы правы, работает если поменять core.setColor(statusID) на какой-нибудь цвет. Непонятно почему цвет определяется но не изменяется.

Comment: После Ваших коррекций текста вопроса, его суть изменилась. Я же  Вам дал ответ на Ваш исходный вопрос, и как мы выяснили, мой ответ верен.

Comment: Да, ваш ответ верный, но что может быть у меня не правильно?

Comment: Потратил еще время на Вашу проблему. Вам нужно сделать так, как я написал в ответе. Если не выходит, значит Вы ошиблись в другом месте, а это у же новый вопрос. Кстати, получив полезную информацию, даже если Вы не решили свою проблему, у взрослых людей принято обозначать ответ, как полезный, в противном случае вряд ли занятой человек, захочет Вам помочь еще раз.